# Python ctypes dll - pass pointer to C structure

Tags: python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I am trying to extract data from a **Hamamatsu C15713** MEMS-FPI spectrometer with the dll, through python `ctypes`.

The dll function I am trying to call is :

```
HRESULT hpkfpi_getdevcount(HPKFPI_INITPARAM* initparam);
```

Where the parameter `initparam` should be a pointer towards a structure:

```
#define HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER 127
#define HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN 32

typedef struct {
  int32_t sizeof_parameter; 
  int32_t devicecount;
  char buf_VID[HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER][HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN];
  char buf_PID[HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER][HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN];
  char buf_SERIAL[HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER][HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN];
} HPKFPI_INITPARAM;
```

My current code:

```py
from ctypes import *


class HPKFPI_INITPARAM(Structure):
    # Define the structure object
    _fields_ = [("sizeof_parameter", c_uint32),("devicecount", c_uint32),
    ('buf_VID', (c_char*127)*32), ('buf_PID', (c_char*127)*32), ('buf_SERIAL', (c_char*127)*32)]


class Hamamatsu_C15713:

    def __init__(self, dll_path):
        dll_filename = os.path.join(dll_path, 'HPKFPI_x64.dll')
        self._dll = windll.LoadLibrary(dll_filename)

        logging.debug(f'dll loaded')

        # Initialize the dll
        self._dll.hpkfpi_init()
     
        # Try to get the device count
        deviceCount = HPKFPI_INITPARAM()
        self._dll.hpkfpi_getdevcount(byref(deviceCount))
```

This code does not produce errors, however the fields of `deviceCount` all remain 0.
Numeric values are 0 and the char arrays are bitstrings value 0.

What have I tried to solve this:
`POINTER(deviceCount)` instead of `byref(deviceCount)` returns an error (TypeError: Not Hashable).
Whatever object I make as `deviceCount`, it is not changed by the function.

Can anyone give me advise?

Comment: Code looks correct, except the arrays should be `(c_char*32)*127`.  The array counts are reversed in Python vs. C when creating the array.  Should you be setting the `sizeof_parameter` field to `sizeof(KPKFPI_INITPARAM)`?  Consult the documentation. I always recommend setting `.argtypes` and `.restype` for each function, but in this case it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not aware the array counts are reversed. What do you mean by regarding the `deviceCount.sizeof_parameter`? would you suggest `deviceCount = HPKFPI_INITPARAM; deviceCount.sizeof_parameter=sizeof(deviceCount)`? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, some structures for backward-compatibility include the size of the structure as the first parameter.  I don't know if that is the case without seeing the documentation, but the naming of the parameter suggests it.  Note for the array counts, you still access the arrays the same way `buf[126]` would access the last `c_char*32`, but to *create* them correctly you have to make `c_char*32` then multiply *that* by 127 for an array of them.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague, we managed advance on this problem.
Important point: There is an error in documentation of the *Hamamatsu C15713 MEMS-FPI spectrometer* dll: The dimensions of the initparam are wrong.

127 should be 255

```py
HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER = 255
HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN = 32

class HPKFPI_INITPARAM(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sizeof_parameter", c_int32),
        ("devicecount", c_int32),
        ('buf_VID', (c_char * HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN) * HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER),
        ('buf_PID', (c_char * HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN) * HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER),
        ('buf_SERIAL', (c_char * HPKFPI_INITARY_STRLEN) * HPKFPI_INITARY_NUMBER)
    ]


class HPKFPI_OPENPARAM(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sizeof_parameter", c_int32),
        ("id", c_int32),
        ("hfpi", HANDLE)
    ]


class Hamamatsu_C15713:
    """
    This class is intended to a a wrapper around the Hamamatsu C15713 dll
    """

    def __init__(self, dll_path):
        logging.debug("Loading dll %s", dll_path)
        # add dll dir to os path env var so dependent dll can be found
        os.environ['PATH'] = str(DLL_DIR) + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
        self._dll = windll.LoadLibrary(str(dll_path))
        logging.debug('dll loaded')

        # Initialize the dll
        ret = self._dll.hpkfpi_init()
        logging.debug("init ret: %s", ret)
        if ret < 0:
            raise SystemError(f"hpkfpi_init failed, ret code: {ret}")

        # Try to get the device count
        init_param = HPKFPI_INITPARAM()
        init_param.sizeof_parameter = sizeof(init_param)
        logging.debug("devcount sizeof: %s",init_param.sizeof_parameter)
        ret = self._dll.hpkfpi_getdevcount(byref(init_param))
        logging.debug("hpkfpi_getdevcount ret: %s", ret)
        if ret < 0:
            raise SystemError(f"hpkfpi_getdevcount failed, ret code: {ret}")

        logging.debug(
            "Extracted devicecount : %d, VID %s, PID %s, SERIAL %s", init_param.devicecount,
            bytes(init_param.buf_VID[0]).decode(),
            bytes(init_param.buf_PID[0]).decode(),
            bytes(init_param.buf_SERIAL[0]).decode())

        open_param = HPKFPI_OPENPARAM()
        open_param.id = 0  # device 0
        open_param.sizeof_parameter = sizeof(open_param)

        ret = self._dll.hpkfpi_open(byref(open_param))
        logging.debug("hpkfpi_open ret: %s", ret)
        if ret < 0:
            raise SystemError(f"hpkfpi_open failed, ret code: {ret}")
        self.dev_handle = open_param.hfpi
        logging.debug("Open handle: %d", self.dev_handle)
```